# Swift: Check if String contains Character?

Tags: string, swift, character, contains

How do I check if a specific `string: String` contains a certain `character: Character`?

Comment: the simplest way i found to solve it in 2020 is:. `s = "hello"` then `s.contains("e")`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
string.contains(character)
```

Example:

```
let string = "Hello, World!"
let character: Character = "e"

if string.contains(character) {
    print("\(string) contains \(character).")
} else {
    print("\(string) doesn't contain \(character).")
}
```

Comment: Swift 5 says: "error: 'characters' is unavailable: Please use String directly", so you can skip `.characters` and call `string.contains(character)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
let char: Character = "e"

let string: String = "William"

let result = string.rangeOfString("\(char)")

if let result = result {
    //The string contains the character
    print("It contains")
}else{
    //The string doesn't contain the character
    print("It doesn't contain")
}
```