# Counting different Characters in Swift

Tags: string, swift, for-loop, character

I am new to swift and I am trying to `count` the different `characters` in a `string` but my code returns the value for the whole `String`

for **example**:

```
var string aString = "aabb"
aString.characters.count()             //returns 5

counter = 0
let a = "a"

for a in aString.characters {
  counter++
}                                      //equally returns 5
```

Can somebody explain why this is happening and how I could count the different *chars*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Check if String contains Character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346666/swift-check-if-string-contains-character)

Comment: there is A LOT wrong with your code: what is `string` doing there? count is a member, not a function and it returns 4 - get your facts right

Comment: Ok, just for clarification. Given the input string `aabb` what output to you expect? `4`? `2`?

Comment: and choose a better example data in the future - 2 as expected result could be the different characters, the number of as, the number of bs, the highest number of occurences of one string, etc. what would you expect to happen for the input `abcdaab`?

Comment: If you're trying to count the number of `a`s in your string, you could do `for char in aString.characters where char == "a" {
    counter++
}`

Comment: @luk2302: exactly, I was reserving that `refinement` for the next question :-)

Comment: Please respond Markus, we are trying to help you here.

Comment: Thanks, I should have expressed myself a little bit better. But Thanks anyway for trying to help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks there is some confusion about what you really need.

I tried to answer to the 5 most likely interpretations.

```
var word = "aabb"

let numberOfChars = word.characters.count // 4
let numberOfDistinctChars = Set(word.characters).count // 2
let occurrenciesOfA = word.characters.filter { $0 == "A" }.count // 0
let occurrenciesOfa = word.characters.filter { $0 == "a" }.count // 2
let occurrenciesOfACaseInsensitive = word.characters.filter { $0 == "A" || $0 == "a" }.count // 2

print(occurrenciesOfA)
print(occurrenciesOfa)
print(occurrenciesOfACaseInsensitive)
```

Answer (score 13):

check this

```
var aString = "aabb"
aString.characters.count // 4

var counter = 0
let a = "a" // you newer use this in your code 

for thisIsSingleCharacterInStringCharactersView in aString.characters {
    counter++
}
print(counter) // 4
```

it simply increase your counter for each character

to calculate number of different characters in you string, you probably can use something 'more advanced', like in next example

```
let str = "aabbcsdfaewdsrsfdeewraewd"

let dict = str.characters.reduce([:]) { (d, c) -> Dictionary<Character,Int> in
    var d = d
    let i = d[c] ?? 0
    d[c] = i+1
    return d
}
print(dict) // ["b": 2, "a": 4, "w": 3, "r": 2, "c": 1, "s": 3, "f": 2, "e": 4, "d": 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

You code is quite faulty: it should probably start with

```
let aString = "aabb"
```

The solutions is to get the characters, put them into a set (unique) and then counting the members of the set:

```
let differentChars = Set(aString.characters).count
```

Correctly returns

> `2`

Comment: your code calculate number of different characters in string. by the way, it is nice solution! the guy need to know how many "a" character is in his string (if i understand the question correctly)

Comment: @user3441734 Does he? The question clearly states *count the different characters in a string* - that is **exactly** what my code does.

Comment: i think so from his context 'let a = "a"

for a in aString.characters {
counter++
}'. probably you are right ...

Comment: @user3441734 might be, lets see, if he is trying to do what your answer provides he is very bad at phrasing

Comment: it seems, he is novice in programming. but that is fine, the beginnings are very hard ...

Answer (score 1):

The `characters` property is deprecated, you can use [`components(separatedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-components) to find how many characters in a String. eg,

```
extension String {

    public func numberOfOccurrences(_ string: String) -> Int {
        return components(separatedBy: string).count - 1
    }

}
let aString = "aabbaa"
let aCount = aString.numberOfOccurrences("a") // aCount = 4
```

Comment: No need for that. You can still use the existing answers, you just need to remove "characters". Like: `word.filter { $0 == "A" }.count`

Comment: @Jerome Li Your solution works everytime and I would prefer that over a solution which uses a filter (loops). But I am not able to figure out what is the logic behind it that it works? It seperates all the non matching character set into a distinct element in the array. But how does counting the occurences of it gives us the exact answer. Can you help explain?

Answer (score 0):

Updated @Luca Angeletti's answer for **Swift5.3** because `characters` property is unavailable in newer swift version.

```
var word = "aabb"

let numberOfChars = word.count // 4
let numberOfDistinctChars = Set(word).count // 2
let occurrenciesOfA = word.filter { $0 == "A" }.count // 0
let occurrenciesOfa = word.filter { $0 == "a" }.count // 2
let occurrenciesOfACaseInsensitive = word.filter { $0 == "A" || $0 == "a" }.count // 2

print(numberOfChars)
print(numberOfDistinctChars)
print(occurrenciesOfA)
print(occurrenciesOfa)
print(occurrenciesOfACaseInsensitive)
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a dictionary out of a sequence of (key, value) pairs. If we can guarantee that the keys are unique, we can use Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:).

```
func characterFrequencies(of string: String) -> Dictionary<String.Element, Int> {
    let frequencyPair = string.map { ($0, 1) }
    return Dictionary(frequencyPair, uniquingKeysWith: +)
}
```

Usage : print(characterFrequencies(of: "Happy"))
Result : ["a": 1, "H": 1, "y": 1, "p": 2]

Answer (score 0):

```
func repeatedCharaterPrint(inputArray: [String]) -> [String:Int] {
var dict = [String:Int]()
if inputArray.count > 0 {
    for char in inputArray {
        if let keyExists = dict[char], keyExists != nil {
            dict[char] = Int(dict[char] ?? 0) + 1
        }else {
            dict[char] = 1
        }
    }
}
return dict
```

}

```
let aa = ["a","s","f","s","l","s"]
print(repeatedCharaterPrint(inputArray: aa))
//Answer : "["s": 3, "l": 1, "a": 1, "f": 1]"
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution is written using hash function , so computation time would be O(1). good for long strings.

//Extension On String and Characters to get Ascii values and Char from Ascii

```
extension Character {
    //Get Ascii Value of Char
    var asciiValue:UInt32? {
        return String(self).unicodeScalars.filter{$0.isASCII}.first?.value
    }
}

extension String {
    //Char Char from Ascii Value
    init(unicodeScalar: UnicodeScalar) {
        self.init(Character(unicodeScalar))
    }


init?(unicodeCodepoint: Int) {
    if let unicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(unicodeCodepoint) {
        self.init(unicodeScalar: unicodeScalar)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}


static func +(lhs: String, rhs: Int) -> String {
    return lhs + String(unicodeCodepoint: rhs)!
}


static func +=(lhs: inout String, rhs: Int) {
    lhs = lhs + rhs
}
}

extension String {
    ///Get Char at Index from String
    var length: Int {
        return self.characters.count
    }

subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return self[Range(i ..< i + 1)]
}

func substring(from: Int) -> String {
    return self[Range(min(from, length) ..< length)]
}

func substring(to: Int) -> String {
    return self[Range(0 ..< max(0, to))]
}

subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: max(0, min(length, r.lowerBound)),
                                        upper: min(length, max(0, r.upperBound))))
    let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
    let end = index(start, offsetBy: range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    return self[Range(start ..< end)]
}

}
```

//Program :

```
let  strk = "aacncjkvkevkklvkdsjkbvjsdbvjkbsdjkvbjdsbvjkbsvbkjwlnkneilhfleknkeiohlgblehgilkbskdbvjdsbvjkdsbvbbvsbdvjlbsdvjbvjkdbvbsjdbjsbvjbdjbjbjkbjkvbjkbdvjbdjkvbjdbvjdbvjbvjdsbjkvbdsjvbkjsbvadvbjkenevknkenvnekvjksbdjvbjkbjbvbkjvbjdsbvjkbdskjvbdsbvjkdsbkvbsdkjbvkjsbvjsbdjkvbdsbvjkbdsvjbdefghaj"

print(strk)

//Declare array of fixes size 26 (characters) or you can say it as a hash table 
var freq = [Int](repeatElement(0, count: 26))

func hashFunc(char : Character) -> UInt32 {
    guard let ascii = char.asciiValue else {
        return 0
    }
    return ascii - 97 //97 used for ascii value of a
}


func countFre(string:String) {

    for i in 0 ... string.characters.count-1 {
        let charAtIndex = string[i].characters.first!
        let index = hashFunc(char: charAtIndex)
        let currentVal = freq[Int(index)]
        freq[Int(index)] = currentVal + 1
        //print("CurrentVal of \(charAtIndex) with index \(index) is \(currentVal)")

    }

    for charIndex in 0 ..< 26 {
        print(String(unicodeCodepoint: charIndex+97)!,freq[charIndex])
    }
}

countFre(string: strk)
```